# Does MySQL DECIMAL datatype force decimal points for integers?

Tags: mysql

Bit of an unusual question, but I have setup a field inside a MySQL table that is of the datatype "DECIMAL(5,2)". As far as I understand this, what I have done is to only allow numbers from -999.99 up to 999.99 to be inserted into this field.

However, when I insert an integer to the value of 26 (which is valid) I am shown this inside the database as 26 not 26.00 - is this normal MySQL behaviour? I (perhaps naively) thought that because I have set the scale to 2, my numbers would always be shown with 2 decimal places?

My question is - do integers inside MySQL "DECIMAL" datatypes always display without any decimals places? Or is this my database manager tool formatting 26.00 to 26 for me?

This may seem like a bit of a weird question but I am still trying to get my head around MySQL DECIMALs. Thanks.

Comment: Not a weird question at all.  MySQL definitely stores your integer in fixed-point format as 26.00; what is the database manager tool that you're using to view the data?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's EMS SQL Manager 2010 on Windows 7 (http://www.sqlmanager.net/products/mysql/manager/)

Comment: What do you see if you use the standard MySQL tools? If in doubt, it's always handy to use the "reference" toolset.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that installed on my PC (it's a work computer), but I've just realised that I have PHPMyAdmin. I'll check that quickly.

Comment: Hmmm... It might be my tool on second thoughts as PHPMyAdmin displays the value as 26.00 (as I originally thought MySQL would)

Comment: What [format specification](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/mysql/manager/documentation/hs18.html) have you configured for floating-point types in SQL Manager's [environment options](http://www.sqlmanager.net/en/products/mysql/manager/documentation/hs1111603.html)? (I accept that `DECIMAL` is not actually floating-point, but since there's no option for fixed-point it's possible that SQL Manager internally converts such types to floating-point before rendering the display).

Comment: Nothing from the default specification as far as I am aware, thanks for pointing me to the right place to fix this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer out, it seems my MySQL database manager is helpfully (or not so helpfully) hiding the decimals from me. For anyone who finds this vaguely useful I am using EMS SQL Manager 2010 on Windows 7. Credit due to Cylindric who prompted me to check my tools!

In answer to my original question - yes, even integers inside a "DECIMAL" datatype will display the decimal places. For example:

```
DECIMAL(3,1)

42 = 42.0
531.2 = 99.9
5 = 5.0
```

Hope this helps someone somewhere!

Comment: 531.2 in a DECIMAL(3,1)? That's going to be out of range and leave you with 99.9

Comment: Thank you, it has been amended.